Как адаптировать сайт на css?
При помощи @media only screen я написал адаптивный сайт который работает в окне браузера размером с телефон, но на настоящем телефоне все съезжает. Когда я редактирую код в файловом менеджере ничего не происходит. Возможно это из-за того, что я использовал position: center?

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask // Возможно это из-за того, что я использовал position: center? приложите код пожалуйста к вопросу => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

@Grundy, серьёзно?? Это ж очевидно на дубликат meta viewport.

Я использовал этот тег, но все ровно не получилось. Дело в том что я занимаюсь фронт разработкой недавно, было бы славно если бы вы рассказали по подробнее

@Glebsheek, смотри по ссылкам дубликатов. Ну и по этим двум словам отлично гуглится. Если работает на компе, но не на телефоне при одинаковой ширине, то 99%, что дело в нём.

Хорошо, спасибо

@Qwertiy, если б была разметка можно было бы сказать - а так, неизвестно, в принципе что угодно может быть

@Grundy, например?

@Qwertiy, какое-то расширение в браузере
